# How can I write a Type Declaration for a JSX attribute from Google AMP that uses square brackets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amp-html

To use AMP's [binding feature](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#%3Camp-state%3E-specification), you have to use special attributes that wrap an element's property with square brackets and links it to an expression. Here is an example from AMP:

```
<p [text]="'Hello ' + foo">Hello World</p>

<button on="tap:AMP.setState({foo: 'amp-bind'})">
```

The problem is, there is currently no @types/amp and Typescript is throwing an error at the first `[` in my JSX saying `[ts] identifier expected`. Messing around with it I have also had `[ts] Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.`

This is most likely solvable by the right Typescript type declaration. Any suggestions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with type definitions - that's just not valid JSX/TSX syntax. Look at [`react-amphtml`](https://github.com/dfrankland/react-amphtml/blob/master/src/helpers/Bind.js) for an example of how to do something like this.

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks for your suggestion. I had messed around with that package before and it does seem to help here (as well as just creating an object with a string key that is my `[property]` attribute and spreading that object in my html element).

But for some reason, with either solution Storybook is stripping out these attributes! And I can't figure out why that is. It works on my localhost version of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [amp-bind component](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/?format=websites) document:

> Bracket characters [ and ] in attribute names can be problematic when
>   writing XML (e.g. XHTML, JSX) or writing attributes via DOM APIs. In
>   these cases, use the alternative syntax data-amp-bind-x="foo" instead
>   of [x]="foo".
>   For example:

```
<p data-amp-bind-text="'Hello ' + foo">Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Yes since my question they added support for this syntax! Thanks for leaving the answer Masih.